# ? null problem when change java to kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, null

I'm trying to change my program from java to kotlin so I use "Convert Java File to Kotlin File"
but it has many errors I can't resolve it by myself.

[image]

In `var block:Array< Array < Block>>? = null`
It's OK to write this?
it's have a red line on `{ arrayOfNulls(3) }`
[image]
and this one

In this class, I Think 'Block?' is a problem.

```
private fun getBlock(y: Int, x: Int): Block? {
    return if (y < 0 || x < 0 || y >= verticalBlockNum || x > horizontalBlockNum) {
        null
    } else block!![y][x]
}
```

---

here is my errors

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9PMC.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nystH.jpg)

[error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7fPD.jpg)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please don't post pictures of code but rather the code itself and the error message. this makes it easier to find for other people. :) and please try to be a bit more specific when describing your problem. do not just say: it does not work, pls fix it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix `arrayOfNulls` you should specify type of element in Array: `arrayOfNulls<Block>(3)`.

Second problem that method `getBlock()` return type is nullable, but array is declared so that it can't contains null, you can fix it to declare nullable array :

```
val targetBlock: Array<Array<Block?>> = Array(3) { arrayOfNulls<Block?>(3) }
```

or without explicit type declaration:

```
val targetBlock = Array(3) { arrayOfNulls<Block?>(3) }
```